# Get top 1 row for every ID

Tags: sql, ms-access

There is a few posts about it but i can't make it work...
I just want to select just one row per ID, something like row_number() over Partition in oracle but in access.

ty

```
SELECT a.*
FROM DATA as a
WHERE a.a_sku = (SELECT top 1 b.a_sku
           FROM DATA as b
           WHERE a.a_sku = b.a_sku)
```

but i get the same table Data out of it

Sample of table DATA
https://ibb.co/X4492fY

Comment: I can't see your data, but it sounds like you just want to use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: too much columns to aggregate and for me it doesn't mater what row it will be unique...if there is a simpler method i would prefer. ty

Comment: Post sample data and expected results in text format.

Comment: @Sátiro "One row per ID" is very ambiguous. Take the first ID in your example data. The ID from this row is repeated in the table with different values in other columns. How should this be sorted? Your question provides no indication on this. Please elaborate on what it is you want, preferably with examples, and we can give you an accurate answer.

Comment: yes, table has forty columns in some there are diferent values within the same ID, but doesn't matter, they are irrelevant for what i want...only want the first column of each ID, can you help pls

Comment: @Sátiro You have shared a picture of the table as it currently is, please share an example, or type out an example, of what you want the result to be because your explanation hasn't made it any clearer what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You should try below query -

```
SELECT a.*
FROM DATA as a
WHERE a.Active = (SELECT b.Active
                  FROM DATA as b
                  WHERE a.a_sku = b.a_sku
                  AND a.Active < b.Active)
```

Comment: doesn't work...i already filtered attributes that i want, now just want get one ID of each. your query just gives me a blank table

Comment: @Sátiro, Try now.

Comment: @Sátiro, May you please give it a try now?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care which record within each group of records with a matching `a_sku` values is returned, you can use the `First` or `Last` functions, e.g.:

```
select t.a_sku, first(t.field2), first(t.field3), ..., first(t.fieldN)
from data t
group by t.a_sku
```